# Lua Math.random and if statement

Tags: if-statement, math, lua, coronasdk

the purpose of the code is to produce a random number and based na the number produced to do a certain thing.

```
local x = math.random(1,2)
if x = 1 then
  print("x = 1")
  else
    print("x > 1")
  end
```

However when I run the code I get the following error "'the'" expected near '='"
and I still dont seem to get why it is not working, so could somebody please lend me a hand? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double equals `==` for equality testing, `=` is for assignment in lua. http://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html

Comment: ok, I feel really dumb now since I have red this so many times :D thanks :)